# Merge dataframe/panel to allow for export to *ONE* excel sheet, not multiple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

When running the following code:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import xlrd
import xlwt

start = dt.datetime.strptime("8/11/2017", "%m/%d/%Y")
end = dt.datetime.today()

book = xlrd.open_workbook('Example.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Okay')
data = sheet.col_values(0, 1)
##print(data)

df = web.DataReader(data, 'yahoo', start, end)
print(df)

resultingdf = pd.concat([data], axis=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

However, when I cease from concat-ing, and just print the dataframe, it shows as this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 6 (items) x 79 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: Adj Close to Volume
Major_axis axis: 2017-12-01 00:00:00 to 2017-08-11 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: AAPL to UCTT
```

I'm obviously missing something, but it appears the code doesn't want to run properly because it doesn't want to concat a list... but the output the line prior classifies it not as a list, but as a panel, which can be concat'd. Hmmm

My end goal is to be able to allow for writing of the entire dataframe to ONE excel sheet, ideally with the open, close, high, low, volume of one stock being listed before moving on to the open, close, etc. of another; that's more of a secondary objective however. As it stands, if I were to write this to an excel sheet it would write the 'open prices' for each stock on one tab, the 'close prices' on another, and so on and so forth, leaving me with 5+ tabs. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sheet.col_values` returns a slice while `web.DataReader returns` a dataframe and the errors tells `concat` expects a dataframe.

You probably want to replace `resultingdf = pd.concat([data], axis=1)` by `resultingdf = pd.concat([df], axis=1)`